# Using linq what is the easiest way to conv list<long> to list<int>?

Tags: linq

Using link what is the easiest way to convert a list of longs to a list of ints?

I need it to be a list, if it cant be possibly i would like to see a solution with a int array or some kind f int container.

Comment: How do you want to handle cases where the value is too large for an int?

Comment: They wont be, for all i care an exception can be thrown. They will always be <= 2000.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You dont need LINQ. Simply do:

```
List<int> intlist = longlist.ConvertAll(x => (int)x);
```

If you really do want LINQ:

```
var intlist = longlist.Select(x => (int) x).ToList();
```

Comment: I personally feel LINQ is better, as it'll work on any `IEnumerable`, not just `List<T>`. Although `ConvertAll()` is more backwards-compatible.

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE**: as pointed out by some commenters, the following answer is incorrect. As stated in the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx),

> If an element cannot be cast to type TResult, this method will throw
>   an exception.

I suspect, but am unable to test right now, that this means anything that can be implicitly cast (e.g. `int` to `long` or subtype to supertype) will work while everything else will cause an exception. In particular, even explicit casts (e.g. `long` to `int`) will fail.

**/UPDATE**

You need to be aware of the possibility of data loss since some of the longs may have a value outside the range supported by an int.

```
        List<long> a = new List<long>();
        List<int> b = a.Cast<int>().ToList();
```

Comment: Yes, .Cast<> is the linq way to go.

Comment: unaccepted. I got an invalid cast exception. I should have ran this before going to bed. The code below is an example of the exception.
                var a = new List<long>();
                a.Add(5);
                a.Add(5);
                a.Add(5);
                a.Cast<int>().ToList();

Comment: Actually if you add a value into a in your example it too will cause an exception.

Comment: This is just plain wrong. The `Cast` method does not perform conversion casts like this (specifically, boxed longs cannot be unboxed to ints). The code given will always throw exceptions with non-empty lists.

Comment: @Porges yes, you're right, I've updated the answer with an update giving more detail on this point.

Comment: This is incorrect. `(new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 }).Cast<long>()` throws an InvalidCastException

Answer (score 3):

```
var myIntList = myLongList.Select(x => (int)x).ToList();
```

Doesn't handle `long` values larger than `int` can hold correctly, although there's not really any way around that.

Answer (score -2):

```
longList.Select( i => (int)i);
```

Nice and easy.